# I tried reinstalling yarn but after re-installing I found this problem, Error: Cannot find module '/home/fiii/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.17.cjs'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, yarnpkg

I tried reinstalling yarn but after re-installing I found this problem, I've tried searching the internet but haven't found a solution.

```
fiii@neo:~$ yarn --version
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/fiii/.yarn/releases/yarn-1.22.17.cjs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Running `rm ~/.yarnrc` and `rm ~/.yarnrc.yml` and worked for me. Don't worry if either file isn't there. `~/.yarnrc` was not found in my case so I ended up deleting `~/.yarnrc.yml` only. I logged out and in to the terminal and ran yarn --version and got `1.22.5`

Why does this solution work
When I ran `npm install -g yarn` or `npm install -g yarn@berry` `yarnrc` and/or `yarnrc.yml` were/was created with the yarnPath pointing to `/home/[username]/.yarn/releases/yarn-berry.cjs`. Running `yarn --version` would run a lookup for `yarn-berry.cjs` based on the yarnPath Since `yarn-berry.cjs` wasn't there the runtime would trigger an appropriate error hence it makes sense that removing `yarnrc` and/or `yarnrc.yml` solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks Alot @Gilberto Vásquez My Issue Got Fixed